# Writing libreoffice-calc macros in Visual Studio Code

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I'd like to write libreoffice-calc macros (libreoffice-basic) in Visual Studio Code instead of the embedded macro editor.

I know `xlwings` enables such functionality when working with excel, as explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoO-Fx0fTpM&ab_channel=xlwings),  using `xlwings vba edit`. But I have no idea how to do it using libreoffice calc.

Any idea?

Comment: Not sure how `xlwings` works, but I use Vim to write python-uno macros, and I have occasionally done this with LO Basic macros as well. The built-in editor for Basic is decent but has some drawbacks, so it's not a bad idea to use an external editor instead. In typical XML syntax, the `.xba` files where the code is stored use `&quot;` and `&amp;` instead of direct punctuation, so I just type it that way, but maybe you can get VS Code to do that for you automatically. You'd also have to update `script.xlb` if you add new modules.